# How do NTFS permissions become improperly ordered?

Tags: security, filesystems, network-share, ntfs

I have some files on a network share and they were read-only accessible to users. I had set the permissions to provide full rights to all domain users - when I checked the main folder, this was still set, but at deeper levels it was sent to read-only. When I right-clicked on the child folder it told me that the permissions where improperly ordered and then allowed me to reorder them. How does this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no one definitive way for them to get out of order, it can happen a few different ways. Some that I've run into:

- Making a rights change and hitting *cancel cancel OMG cancel* in a panic before it gets done applying (kinda bad if you do it at the top of a 4-million file directory tree).
- Command-line utilities (I'm thinking `xcacls`, I believe) that didn't respect ordering, you could shoot yourself in the foot easily that way.
- Backup utilities that misbehave on restore.

There are probably more!

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful - and I enjoyed the humor as well. I can identify with the "cancel cancel OMG cancel" panic as well.